# C - Struct definition

Tags: c, struct

In the struct below why does the char for the `firstName` and `surname` not have a character amount for each of those fields? Like `[20]` for example, which would state that `firstName` will have space for 20 characters.

```
struct Student
{
  char * firstName;
  char * surname;
  int studentID;
  int GPA;
 };
```

Comment: they're just a pointers to a char, you can `malloc` their size later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have declared `firstName` and `surname` as a pointer. so you need to allocate memory for those structure members externally. without allocating memory for those members, you cant store strings in it.

This is one way of allocating memory-

```
 struct Student
 {
  char * firstName;
  char * surname;
  int studentID;
  int GPA;
 }stu1;

 stu1->firstName=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
 stu1->surname=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
```

Another way of allocating-

```
 struct Student
 {
  char * firstName;
  char * surname;
  int studentID;
  int GPA;
 };
 struct Student *stu1;
 stu1=(struct Student *)malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
 stu1->firstName=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
 stu1->surname=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
```

If you allocate memory dynamically don't forget `free()` it at the end!

Answer (score 1):

Sathish is correct. For completeness, an alternative way to do it to declare an array of characters in the struct. firstName and surname would then have allocated storage.

```
 struct Student
 {
     char firstName[20];
     char surname[20];
     int studentID;
     int GPA;
} stu1;

strncpy( stu1.firstName, "be_careful_of_really_long_names", 20);
stu1.firstName[19] =0;
printf("%s", stu1.firstName); // 'be_careful_of_reall'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char * firstname;
char * surname;
```

Are pointers. Meaning, they point to a memory location somewhere. BUT you have to create/allocate that memory to the size you need. Unless you allocate the space for it, it will point to an undefined address.

Here is an example:

```
Student student;

student.firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
student.surname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

strcpy_s(student.firstName, 6, "Frank");
strcpy_s(student.surname, 5, "Dill");

printf("first name: %s\n", student.firstName);
printf("sur name: %s", student.surname);
```

You can use strcpy_s to copy the name to the buffer. adding 1 extra length to account for the null terminated character. Also don't forget to free the memory you allocated with malloc when you are done with it

Answer (score 0):

the * is used as a pointer, and so will point to the position in memory named 'firstName' of size char. It won't, however, set the size to be 20.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned `malloc` in my answer, and so has @Sathish in his answer.

You can also use a function like `strcpy` to copy strings to the pointer.

Here is an example of how this might be used:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student
{
  char * firstName;
  char * surname;
  int studentID;
  int GPA;
 };


int main()
{

 struct Student example;
 printf("Size of example %d\n", sizeof(example));

 strcpy(example.firstName, "James");

 printf("The Student's name is: %s", example.firstName);
 printf("Size of example %d\n", sizeof(example));

 return 0;
}
```

Notice that the size of the structure stays the same because your struct only stores a memory location for where to get the `firstName` and `surname`.